# How to set fixed dimensions for images on desktop only in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page I made using twitter bootstrap . Everything works fine, but i would like to set  manual height and width to some images when the site is viewed on Desktop (for eg height:30px ; width:60px:) . I do not want these dimensions to apply to tablet or Mobile phone. How do i achieve this?

Comment: `width:auto;height:auto`. Show some code and the result of your efforts please

Comment: i want to basically give specific height for example 30px . but this should apply only on desktop and not on tablet and phone.

Comment: Use media query in your css:
`@media (min-width: 980px) { ... desktop only css ... }`

Comment: will that override any bootstrap css?  Also since i want to do this only for a few images what class name do i put in the <img> tag?.

Comment: Can somebody give me an exampe of adding media query

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes `.visible-desktop` and `hidden-desktop`than put a optimized image version of desired width and height inside those div

[for example check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/TagtP/5/show/)